# JS: Display array item in textbox with onclick event?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a problem but I cannot figure it why it's not working. All I am trying to do is store input values into array and show them into a textbox with onclick event handler. Could anyone help me please?

Here is my code (html, css, javascript): https://jsfiddle.net/3486kwtn/

Only Javascript:

```
//FUNCTION
            var $ = function (id) {
                return document.getElementById(id);
            }

//ONLOAD EVENT HANDLER
            window.onload = function () {
            var taskList = [];
            var newTask = $("new_task");
            var scr = $("task_list");
            var nextTask = $("next_task")

            $("add_task").onclick =
                function () {
                    taskList.push(newTask.value);
                    scr.innerHTML = taskList.join("\n");
                    clear();
                }

                $("show_next_task").onclick =
                    function () {
                        nextTask.push(scr.value);
                        nextTask.innerHTML = taskList;
                        taskList.shift(); }

            function clear() {
                newTask.value = "";

            }

            }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Your code is working as it is with no changes.. In JSfiddle, window.onload wont work. Try your code on a simple html file and load on your browser.

Comment: @Manu No I don't see any error in debugger.

Comment: @Sachin Still no luck. :(

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing jQuery and Javascript syntax:

`$("show_next_task").onclick` this doesn't make sense.

Either you use jQuery (if you use jQuery don't forget to add it):

```
$("#show_next_task").on("click", function(){
// do something here
});
```

Or use javascript:

```
document.getElementById("show_next_task").onclick = function(){
// do something here
}
```

Or

```
document.getElementById("show_next_task").addEventListener("click",function(evt){
// do something here
},false);
```

EDIT:

I didn't notice you have a $ function.

The problem with your fiddle was actually the `window.onload =..` in jsFiddle you don't need it as the script part is already in the window.onload:
http://jsfiddle.net/3486kwtn/8/

Comment: I edited the code but still cant get it work. Don't know why. When I click `Add Task` button, the value doesn't show up in the text area as well as when I click on `Show Next Task`. :(

Comment: because your other code is not correct... check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3486kwtn/15/

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seem working in fiddle however is not working on my any browser. I don't need an `if` statement to remove item from `Item List`. I can use `shift()` method also.

Comment: I didn't remove, the button didn't say remove task, it said show next task. if that's what your button says that's what it should do (from UX perspective)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the proper way to do it but it does what i need to do:

```
//FUNCTION
            var $ = function (id) {
                return document.getElementById(id);
            }

//ONLOAD EVENT HANDLER
            window.onload = function () {
            var taskList = [];
            var newTask = $("new_task");
            var scr = $("task_list");
            var nextTask = $("next_task");

            $("add_task").onclick =
                function () {
                    taskList.push(newTask.value);
                    scr.innerHTML = taskList.join("\n");
                    clear();
                 }

                $("show_next_task").onclick =
                  function () {
                    nextTask.value = taskList[0];
                    taskList.shift();
                  }

            function clear() {
                newTask.value = "";

                  }

            }
```